# Emacs and chord translation

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, slime

I'm having some issues with emacs, in particular when using SLIME. It's not reading the slime-eval-defun command (bound to C-M-x) but will read C-M-S-x... same issue with the indent function C-X-q, I have to add a shift to make it work.

When looking into the key bindings I get this

```
C-M-x (translated from C-M-S-x) runs the command slime-eval-defun,
which is an interactive Lisp function in `slime.el'.
```

So it picks up C-M-S-x and assumes that I want C-M-x, which is true, but I'm not getting why it's not picking up C-M-x in the first place!

I'm running emacs on Arch as a guest OS, host OS is OS X.

Comment: Some VM 'things' have an escape key so that key presses are sent to the host rather than the guest - is some combination of C-M-S the escape key?

Comment: No such problem with the native OS X Emacs (`Meta` bound to `Option` in terminal). So @MrBones must be right suggesting the issue is with the VM.

Comment: No I'm not having problems with native OS X Emacs either. I'm using VirtualBox from Oracle, and the host key is the apple command key. That's the only escaped key that I know of, there are no other settings in the VM that mention escaped sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that the KDE default shortcut for activating clipboard actions is C-M-x. I removed that and the SLIME shortcut works now.